# Why couldn't Jack use his powers to bring this person back?

Tags: supernatural

In season 14 episode 18, Jack has killed

> Mary Winchester by disintegrating her.

He goes through lengths to get

> Rowena to create a spell that will bring this person back, but the body that was eventually brought back was just a replica.

Why couldn't Jack have just used his powers directly to reconstruct this person's body on a subatomic level, and then subsequently resurrect them?

We know powerful angels can bring a dead body back to life, like Castiel did with Bobby in season 5; we also know a body can be reconstructed, as God did with Castiel, and the angels somehow did with Adam Winchester after Sam and Dean burned his body.

So what gives? Is Jack just too young to utilise the full extent of his powers?

Comment: Maybe the Reapers would interfere with the more direct angelic approach to resurrection. They're not huge fans of the Winchesters.

Comment: This question contained several spoilers for the latest Supernatural episodes, so I added some spoiler sections. Please check and make sure I didn't alter the meaning of your question. Good question btw, my +1.